# How to print star pattern in COBOL?

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I tried to print star pattern in cobol. I have constructed the following code. But I think it can be optimized. And also I need to take multiple inputs at run time. Cannot accept inputs at run time. Can anyone guide me?

```
 IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
 PROGRAM-ID. HELLO.
 DATA DIVISION.
 WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
 01 WS-TABLE.
  05 WS-A OCCURS 10 TIMES INDEXED BY I.
     10 WS-B PIC X(1).
     10 WS-C PIC X(1) OCCURS 10 TIMES INDEXED BY J.
01 N PIC 9(1).
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
ACCEPT N.
PERFORM A-PARA VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL I>N.
PERFORM C-PARA VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL I>N.
STOP RUN.
A-PARA.
PERFORM B-PARA VARYING J FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL J>I.
B-PARA.
MOVE '*' TO WS-C(I,J).
C-PARA.
DISPLAY WS-A(I).
```

Answer (score 1):

Sayantan Sur, Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's good to know that you've solved your own question and have posted them as answers. You don't have to post 2 answers when you can `edit` the 1st answer for any updates/improvement/optimized solution. `edit` option is just below your answer, in between `share` and `flag`.

Regarding your question, 
You can have just one `PERFORM` loop to print asterisks pattern. Please take a look at the following code.

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. HELLO-WORLD.

DATA DIVISION. 
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 WS-OUT PIC X(80) VALUE SPACES.
01 WS-I PIC 9(2) VALUE 0. 
01 WS-N PIC 9(2) VALUE 5. 
01 WS-CENTER PIC 9(2) VALUE 1.  

PROCEDURE DIVISION.

PERFORM VARYING WS-I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL WS-I > WS-N
MOVE ALL '*' TO WS-OUT(WS-CENTER:WS-I)
DISPLAY WS-OUT
END-PERFORM. 

STOP RUN.
```

**Note:** In the above code snippet, I didn't include steps to take inputs at run time. Instead, I've used `VALUE` clause to assign input to `WS-N`.

**Alternatively,** you can also make use of the following code. Thanks to *Rick Smith* for the valuable suggestions.

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. HELLO-WORLD.

DATA DIVISION. 
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 WS-OUT PIC X(10) VALUE ALL '*'.
01 WS-I PIC 9(2) VALUE 0. 
01 WS-N PIC 9(2) VALUE 5. 
01 WS-CENTER PIC 9(2) VALUE 1.  

PROCEDURE DIVISION.

PERFORM VARYING WS-I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL WS-I > WS-N
DISPLAY WS-OUT(WS-CENTER:WS-I)
END-PERFORM. 

STOP RUN.
```

**Output:** Both codes give the following output.

```
*                                                                               
**                                                                              
***                                                                             
****                                                                            
*****
```

You may try running the code [here](http://tpcg.io/q8TZb7).

Comment: Thank You. It's really helpful.

Comment: If `WS-OUT` were changed to `PIC X(10) VALUE ALL "*"`, the `MOVE` statement may be eliminated and the `DISPLAY` statement may be changed to display the sub-string, `WS-OUT(WS-CENTER:WS-I)`, directly.

Comment: @RickSmith Thanks for the suggestions, I've updated the answer based on your comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. HELLO.
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 WS-TABLE.
   05 WS-A OCCURS 10 TIMES INDEXED BY I.
   10 WS-B PIC X(1) OCCURS 10 TIMES INDEXED BY J.
   01 N PIC 9(2).
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   DISPLAY "ENTER NUMBER OF ROWS: "
   ACCEPT N.
   PERFORM A-PARA UNTIL N>0 AND N<11
   PERFORM B-PARA VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL I>N
           AFTER J FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL J>I
   PERFORM C-PARA VARYING I FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL I>N.
   STOP RUN.
   A-PARA.
   DISPLAY "ENTER VALUE WITHIN 1 AND 10"
   ACCEPT N.
   B-PARA.
   MOVE '*' TO WS-B(I,J).
   C-PARA.
   DISPLAY WS-A(I).
```

Here the loop has been optimized further and even the number of paragraphs has been reduced.

Comment: I do not know about anyone else but I tried to compile this but it did not work - it wanted spaces between varaibles and operators eg J > I not J>I and I, J not I,J, After that it would only accept 10 for N and after that it dis not create a star pattern but a triangle. If you meant creating a triangle of asterisks then say so instaead of making people wonder how you get a star out of that code.

Comment: @NicC - WRT standard COBOL, there is no syntax rule that requires spaces before and after the relational operators `<`, `=`, `>`, `<=`, or `>=`. However, there is a syntax rule that, when a comma is used as a separator, it must be followed by a space.

Comment: @Rick Smith - my mistook. They were warning messages. The only COBOL compiler I have access to is Enterprise Compiler 4.1 which is old (2 versions?) but it is all I have. The interesting thing about running the code is even though I enter 4 in the procedure division it still calls A-PARA and will only exit that if I enter 1 or 10 and then produces a 10 line triangle. Debugging is required!

Comment: @NicC - It appears that you may need to enter the leading zero so the input matches the picture clause, that is, `04` instead of `4`.

Comment: @Rick Smith - spot on! However, there is still a 'fault' somewhere because if I enter 1, no leading zero, it accepts it but as 10. Probably because one blank is x'f140'.

Comment: @NicC - You could insert `DISPLAY QUOTE N(1:2) QUOTE` after the accept to determine whether `N` is `"10"` or `"1 "`. Either way, that would show the runtime behavior for an `ACCEPT` with such a picture clause.

Comment: try this code in open cobol ide 
https://launchpad.net/cobcide/+download

Comment: @Sayantan Sur - I am not going to download an IDE for a 'compiler' that I do not have especially as you tagged the question 'mainframe' and I do have access to a mainframe compiler with the results shown above.